# Are GUIs ever programmed in DirectX for higher performance?

Tags: gui

I've been researching GDI a little and on some websites I'm lead to believe it can hardly draw a few boxes, while on others it can easily be used in an interactive charting application.

So I'm wondering what is used in applications like Excel where there can be a lot movement like scrolling through a large amount of data fast? Could DirectX be used and would it increase performance? Is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of - some of Microsoft's newer APIs such as [Direct2d](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) leverage your graphics card for drawing GUIs. DirectX itself (more specifically Direct3D) isn't *usually* used for GUIs outside of a video game that contains them.